# Reject in ansible list variable

Tags: ansible, jinja

I have such a variable:

```
apps:
 - {name: kapitalism, extension: .war}
 - {name: socialism, extension: .war}
 - {name: somethingelse, extension: .ear}
```

And I need to make another one based on it, which will not include some of the list.
I'm trying this:

```
- name: Reject this please
  set_fact:
    apps: "{{ apps | map(attribute='name') | reject('search',item.name) | list }}"
  when: "item.name.find('socialism') != -1"
  with_items: "{{ apps }}"
```

But here I get such a problem that the extension parameter is lost and I get the variable:

```
apps: [u'kapitalism', u'somethingelse']
```

How to make a variable like this:

```
apps:
 - {name: kapitalism, extension: .war}
 - {name: somethingelse, extension: .ear}
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    apps2: []
    apps:
      - {name: A, extension: .ab}
      - {name: B, extension: .ab}
      - {name: C, extension: .c}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        apps2: "{{ apps2 + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ apps }}"
      when: item.name != 'C'
    - debug:
        var: apps2
```

gives (abridged):

```yaml
  apps2:
  - extension: .ab
    name: A
  - extension: .ab
    name: B
```

The same result can be achieved by [*rejectattr*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#rejectattr)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        apps2: "{{ apps|rejectattr('name', 'match', '^C$') }}"
```

Comment: ty!!! did the first way - everything works.